# Perl wget not "greping" rightly

Tags: perl, web-scraping

anticipated thanks.

This loop delivers URLs ( in the $_ variable) and my idea was to be sending each URL to the wget for processing as you can see

```pl
foreach(@my_array) {
    $browser->get($_);    
    system ("wget -q -O -\"$_\" | grep -oe '\\w*.\\w*@.\\w*.\\w\\+' | sort -u");
}
print EMAILS;
```

The questions:

1) The grep does not grep, I only get the URLs, which are the $_

2) I am not quite sure I am sending the result correctly to the output file, as all I do is print EMAILS, where EMAILS is a handle of a an output file created lines above.

3) I tried to do another variant, putting a >output.txt embedded in that parentheses,

```pl
system ("wget -q -O -\"$_\" | grep -oe '\\w*.\\w*@.\\w*.\\w\\+' > output.txt| sort -u");
```

but it gets ignored

4) Question is whether that grep is done while crawling in the servers or does wget have to download all the files and only then in my computer grep all the emails ? Naturally I dont want to download the whole website.

thank you a lot

Comment: Why don't you explain what your system call is supposed to be doing. You're trying to grep a downloaded webpage?

Comment: yes, the wget receives the URL is has to go to, which is contained in $_. Since it would have to crawl through the whole web it will have the -r recursive command.That grep fetches the emails. However in the output file I only get the list of URLs wget has gone to, but the grep is not delivering me the emails in that perl command, although it did work in the shell

Answer (score 2):

grep is performed after the wget is finished (downloading all the files).  Also, outputting to a file will not pass the correct information to the sort command.

LWP may be more usefull in looking through the webpages for e-mail addresses.

http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP.pm

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a read at it. (positive point for the Marine Corps :) Oh, by the way, actually I am using Mechanize which is derived from LWP, that is where the $browser->$_ is for. but how would you go about that? Using maybe the content command to download it as text? or you mean I could put that regex so that it picks the emails on the spot without having to download ? Curiously Mechanize does have built in functions to fech URLs (that is how I got them) but it does not have that for emails

Comment: @iaintunderstand looks like you would use `$mech->get($uri); $mech->content(...);`  This latter would return the body content which you could use regex to strip the e-mails from. 

http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm

Comment: Yes, I have studied that page quite often and I always wondered about whether by the $mech->content( format => 'text' )
would be the way. The expression "returns" does not mean, download, does it? I would want it to fetch them on site.

Comment: @iaintunderstand "returns" means grab it from the site (download in a sense but store it in memory) and put the result in a variable.  (i.e: `my $pagetext = $mech->content( format => 'text' );`  `print $pagetext;` would print out all the text on the page (no html markup).

Comment: hmm, but imagine, since it is not about one site, I cannot customize Mechanize to go through the web following links, I am passing it rows of URLs .So, what we have so far would be the index page, but the emails are also inside the web. Wget would go through the web with -r but how would mechanize crawl different webs without any customization?

Comment: @iaintunderstand mechanize can get you a list of links via `$mech->links()` which you could iterate through however many levels deep you wanted to with  `$mech->get($link);`

Comment: `grep` is *not* "performed" after the `wget` is finished. `grep` is started as soon as `wget` is. The real question is "when does `wget` start outputting what it receives", and I strongly doubt it's only when it has finished downloading the page. That would be dumb and would require extra work to make happen.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot space before URL:

```
system ("wget -q -O - \"$_\" | grep -oe '\\w*.\\w*@.\\w*.\\w\\+' | sort -u");
```

Comment: Thank you, I can only try that again tomorrow, so I dont know if that could have been the issue. Could it? I did get the urls printed in the file, would that lack of space cause the grep not to work?

Answer (score 1):

Missing space before URL. Rederiction placed to early.

```
system("wget -q -O - \"$_\" | grep -oe '\\w*.\\w*@.\\w*.\\w\\+' | sort -u >output.txt");
```

What makes you think `system` changes `$_`?

Comment: What makes me think system changes $_ ? My visualization of it would be that wget would go to the URLs contained in the $_, download and perform the grepping afterwards. Another question that comes up is how that loop goes about. Does wget get through with all the downloading of a web, do the grep, gets the emails and then continues with the next URL?

Comment: "My visualization of it would be that wget would go to the URLs contained in the $_, download and perform the grepping afterwards." And what part of that do you think changes $_? or even knows of $_?

Comment: `wget` probably outputs what it receives as soon as it receives it, although the output might be buffered (often in 4k chunks).